# How to add/remove class on mouse hover in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add class as I hover over an item and remove it as soon as the hover is removed in JavaScript. For now, my code is not removing the class until I hover over that item again.

```
    myChart.on('mouseover', function(params){
        var collapseItem = params.name + "-content"
        var toCollapse = document.getElementById(collapseItem)
        var collapseHeading = toCollapse.previousElementSibling
        collapseHeading.classList.toggle("active")
    })
```

Comment: Can you use to  :hover css selector?

Comment: @TheKNVB I'm using a chart library and I want to highlight a specific text on my page as I hover the specific item in the graph.

Comment: You have to use  mouseover as well as mouseout to make it work properly.
 myChart.on('mouseout', function(params){
        var collapseItem = params.name + "-content"
        var toCollapse = document.getElementById(collapseItem)
        var collapseHeading = toCollapse.previousElementSibling
        collapseHeading.classList.toggle("active")
        // collapseHeading.classList.remove("active")
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: taken from this post]

you can listen to **mouseout** event (taken from [this post](https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave#:%7E:text=The%20mouseover%20event%20occurs%20when,and%20the%20other%20one%20%E2%80%93%20relatedTarget%20.))

```
function toggleActiveClass(params){
    var collapseItem = params.name + "-content"
    var toCollapse = document.getElementById(collapseItem)
    var collapseHeading = toCollapse.previousElementSibling
    collapseHeading.classList.toggle("active")
}

myChart.on('mouseover', toggleActiveClass);
myChart.on('mouseout', toggleActiveClass);
```

Comment: Just need to remove the extra ')' from the end.

Comment: It worked but slight issue is that sometime mouseover isn't working on adjacent items in chart.

Comment: can you share an example?

Answer (score 2):

is this you want?

```js
var myChart = document.getElementById("tt");
myChart.onmouseover = function(event){
        var collapseItem = event.target.tagName + "-content";

        var toCollapse = document.getElementById(collapseItem);
var collapseHeading = toCollapse.previousElementSibling;
        collapseHeading.classList.toggle("active");

}
```

```css
#tt{
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
background-color: red;
}

.active{
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="tt">
<div id="prev">
</div>

<div id="DIV-content">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "mouseover" as well as "mouseout" to make the toggle or class addition/removal work properly. Currently when your cursor leave there no function to remove the class.

```
function toggleActiveClass(params) {
    var collapseItem = params.name + "-content"    
    var toCollapse = document.getElementById(collapseItem)
    var collapseHeading = toCollapse.previousElementSibling
    collapseHeading.classList.toggle("active")
}

myChart.on('mouseover', toggleActiveClass);
myChart.on('mouseout', toggleActiveClass);
```